# Selecting Most Recent Date Relative to Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

Just stumped on syntax for this...

I have Two tables in mysql & I need to fetch records from Table A when following criteria are met:
1) Name in Table A matches the name in Table B
AND
2) The price for the most recent day in Table B is less than the record in Table A

So...running the query on example tables below would fetch me these two records:

```
03-17-2019    Bob   8
03-20-2019    John  10
```

Essentially, I need to evaluate each row in Table A, check the matching name in Table B that has the most recent date relative to the record under evaluation in Table A, and then determine if the price in Table A is greater than the price for the most recent matching name in Table B.  After that, I need to calculate the difference between the prices.  So, in the two records above, the difference would be 2 and 4

```
Table A
Date       | Name | Price
03-08-2019    Bob   6
03-25-2019    Bob   2
03-17-2019    Bob   8
03-20-2019    John  10

Table B
Date      | Name  |  Price
03-16-2019    Bob   4
03-28-2019    Bob   9
03-02-2019    Bob   12
03-10-2019    John  6
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join twice the tables, once to get the min date difference and then to get the row with the min date difference:

```
select a.*
from tablea a 
inner join tableb b on b.name = a.name 
inner join (
  select a.name, min(abs(datediff(b.date, a.date))) mindatediff
  from tablea a inner join tableb b
  on b.name = a.name
  group by a.name           
) g on g.name = a.name and abs(datediff(b.date, a.date)) = g.mindatediff
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uL5a9Vhwv2LHr7HHTnfUtp/0).
or:

```
select a.*
from tablea a inner join tableb b
on b.name = a.name
where abs(datediff(b.date, a.date)) = (
    select min(abs(datediff(x.date, y.date))) 
    from tablea x inner join tableb y
    where x.name = a.name and y.name = b.name                            
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aajCK9aunYfqZzd3667twE/0).
Results:

```
| date       | name | price |
| ---------- | ---- | ----- |
| 2019-03-17 | Bob  | 8     |
| 2019-03-20 | John | 10    |
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you would use window functions

```
select ab.*, (price - b_price)
from (select a.*, b.price as b_price,
             row_number() over (partition by a.name order by datediff(b.date, a.date) as seqnum
      from a join
           b
           on a.name = b.name and
              a.date >= b.date
     ) ab
where seqnum = 1;
```