# Selecting Most Recent Date Relative to Another Table Not Equal To

Tags: sql, r, database

I'm trying to do something very similar to what this question asks for:

[Selecting Most Recent Date Relative to Another Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987082/selecting-most-recent-date-relative-to-another-table)

Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to leave a comment on it.

Essentially what I want to do is bring in the value from another table with the most recent **but not equal to (less than)** the date in the first table. Also return null if there is no most recent date.

Can someone please help me out here? Thanks!